# How to find similarity between two signals with xcorr in matlab

Tags: matlab, speech

I'm writing a code for speech recognition. I have a number *n* of database, each db contains the same number of words recorded by different persons.

I want to do the `xcorr` between, for example, the reference word "hello" with all the words in the "hello" db and all the words in the "door" db and then the code has to say to me which word is it. I need to make some mathematical paragon in order to make a decision.

Now, I know that the auto correlation between the same word has a symmetric graph. But if I compare the word "hello" said by a male and the same word said by a female it is not symmetric, and I obtain the same result if I compare the word "hello" with the word "door".

My question is: how can I find similarities between the two words doing the xcorr function? Do I need to find the lag or the maximum of the xcorr?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: how can I find similarities between the two words doing the xcorr function? Do I need to find the lag or the maximum of the xcorr?

To measure similarity to a single word recording, you need to take maximum, it's a measure of similarity

> But if I compare the word "hello" said by a male and the same word said by a female it is not symmetric, and I obtain the same result if I compare the word "hello" with the word "door".

To make an optimal decision on which class the sample belongs to, you need to compare similarity measures for both clusters:

```
max(xcorr(sample, hello)) < > max(xcorr(sample, door)
```

the theory behind this is called "Bayes Optimal Classification".

If you have more word samples, you can make a better decision:

```
 max_sample(max_lag(xcorr(sample, hello_sample_i)) < > max_sample(max_lag(xcorr(sample, door_sample_i))
```

> I'm writing a code for speech recognition.

Speech samples are time-varying and xcorr is not invariant to time variation. A better measure would be DTW distance of spectrums for speech. You can find DTW distance implementation here:

http://www.ee.columbia.edu/ln/rosa/matlab/dtw/

DTW is invariant to time shifts, so you would be able to make more reliable decisions.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. 

I believe that find the maximum is not enough. Do I need the position of it too? And how do i make a comparison?

For now, I have an array for each db in which I stored the maximum of each crosscorr. How can I make a judgement if I have got these results for the sample word "hello"? 

"hello db"= [ 8.7729, 14.2898, 7.8010, 4.8641, 5.2716]

 "door" db =[ 8.4145 , 6.7965, 11.2714, 6.4075, 6.7344]

Comment: maximum for hello db is higher, so the word belongs to hello. To make judgement more reliable you need to move to MFCC coefficient and use DTW instead of xcorr like I wrote you before.